# js: get colum of array of objects

Tags: javascript, sql, arrays, sqlite, object

I need your help to get data out of a database. I use sql.js and the db.exec delivers an object res:

```
const res = db.exec('select time_,temp  from sensors where topic=\"/xx/sensors\" limit 10')
```

res looks like this:

```
Array [ {…} ]
​
    0: Object { columns: (2) […], values: (10) […] }
​​
        columns: Array [ "time_", "temp" ]
​​​
            0: "time_"
​​​
            1: "temp"
​​​
            length: 2
​​​
​​
        values: Array(10) [ (2) […], (2) […], (2) […], … ]
​​​
            0: Array [ "23:53:01", 19.51 ]
​​​
            1: Array [ "23:55:01", 19.51 ]
​​​         
            2: Array [ "23:57:01", 19.5 ]
​​​
            3: Array [ "23:59:01", 19.48 ]
​​​
            4: Array [ "00:05:04", 19.47 ]
​​​
            5: Array [ "00:07:04", 19.45 ]
​​​
            6: Array [ "00:09:04", 19.43 ]
​​​
            7: Array [ "00:11:04", 19.43 ]
​​​
            8: Array [ "00:13:04", 19.36 ]
​​​
            9: Array [ "00:15:04", 19.38 ]
​​​
            length: 10
​​​
```

res is an object with arrays that has columns. How can I get the time_ to look like this:

```
const labels = ['00:13:04', '00:15:04', ...];
```

and the temp in this format:

```
data = [19.36, 19.38, ...];
```

Can you please help me?
regards

Comment: Try using the map array method?

Answer (score 0):

Example, res is as following:

```
let res = [['1', 1], ['2', 2]]
```

Then, your required values would be:

```
let labels = res.map(arr => arr[0]);
let data = res.map(arr => arr[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks, Karan, for your reply. I geht the error Array undefined. What do I have to change to adress time_ and temp?  let labels = res.map(arr => time_[0]); let data = res.map(arr => temp[1]); does not work either, 'is not defined' it says. Regards

Comment: You need to access your values array inside the res.

So, either add vals = res[0].values;
And then run the code on them (let labels = vals.map(arr => arr[0]); & let data = vals.map(arr => arr[1]));

Comment: otherwise, just share the exact code that you're using with the exact error.

Answer (score 0):

Your result is an array with a single object in it which in turn has two properties `columns` and `values`. It looks like you are wanting to map the `values` array of this object to two individual arrays by index so you will need to access that property appropriately before mapping:

```
const res = [{ columns: [], values: [] }];

const values = res[0].values;
// or with destructuring
const [{ values }] = res;
```

You can then either [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over this array twice

```js
const res = [
  {
    columns: ['time_', 'temp'],
    values: [['23:53:01', 19.51], ['23:55:01', 19.51], ['23:57:01', 19.5], ['23:59:01', 19.48], ['00:05:04', 19.47], ['00:07:04', 19.45], ['00:09:04', 19.43], ['00:11:04', 19.43], ['00:13:04', 19.36], ['00:15:04', 19.38],],
  },
];

const values = res[0].values;

const labels = values.map((arr) => arr[0]);
const data = values.map((arr) => arr[1]);

console.log('labels: ', labels);
console.log('data: ', data);
```

or use a single pass in a `for` loop (here using [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) each tuple)

```js
const res = [
  {
    columns: ['time_', 'temp'],
    values: [['23:53:01', 19.51], ['23:55:01', 19.51], ['23:57:01', 19.5], ['23:59:01', 19.48], ['00:05:04', 19.47], ['00:07:04', 19.45], ['00:09:04', 19.43], ['00:11:04', 19.43], ['00:13:04', 19.36], ['00:15:04', 19.38],],
  },
];

const labels = [];
const data = [];

for (const [label, datum] of res[0].values) {
  labels.push(label);
  data.push(datum);
}

console.log('labels: ', labels);
console.log('data: ', data);
```

Comment: Thank you, pilchard. I used the .map() way an it worked!